# PHP Login Form Doesn't Redirect

Tags: php, forms, validation, authentication

I have a login form for registered users, but it doesn't seem to want to redirect when proper email and password is entered. Not sure why I am getting back a 0 from my query? Am I missing something obvious?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/db_connect.php');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

// Define $email and $mypassword 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

$qry="SELECT * FROM dontblame WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
  $_SESSION['user']=$email;
  header('location: ../dashboard.php');    
}
else {
    $login_err = "<p>Your email or password is incorrect.</p>";
}
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Edit: This is the error I am getting...

```
FROM dontblame WHERE email='XXXXXXX@gmail.com' and password='e6a52beca192a3fd67c8a0ea52cdea29162dd265'" resource(3) of type (mysql result)
```

Comment: try with the complete url: `header('location: http://localhost/admin/dashboard.php');` something like that.

Comment: Are you storing the password as plain text?

Comment: @yogesh No I am storing as SHA1. I forgot to mention that I am also seeing the error variables under the input fields where I am calling them.

Comment: @tonjaggart So it should be encrypted while used in query. You missed that part. You are directly using the password in query without `SHA1`.

Comment: `$password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha1",$_POST['password']));` try this

Comment: @ModestasStankevičius Tried and still getting $login_err

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha1",$_POST['password']));
```

then use this query:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM dontblame WHERE email='".$email."' and password='".$password."'";
```

But please dont use `mysql_*`. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Tried it and still getting the same errors. I am brand new to PHP and I will definitely read up on what you posted. Thanks for the heads up @ChristianMark

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: This is the error message I am seeing: $login_err = "<p>Your email or password is incorrect.</p>";

Comment: 1st: Do you have `session_start();` on your `dashboard.php`? 2nd: What are the contents of your `dashboard.php`? 3rd: Have you tried the query on backend(phpmyadmin)?

Comment: 1. Yes and this is the error I am dumping on login.php FROM dontblame WHERE email='XXXXXXX@gmail.com' and password='e6a52beca192a3fd67c8a0ea52cdea29162dd265'" resource(3) of type (mysql result)

Comment: Can you post your table structure with metadata?

Comment: No idea how to do that :( Sorry this is my 3rd day with PHP...

Comment: I mean in your database. Maybe there is no content or the algorithm is incorrect or the size of the varchar you are storing is insufficient for the length of sha1 hash.

Comment: Oh got it. password varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No

Comment: Well that is somehow strange. Can you post the whole table structure? I'll provide you the query afterwards.

Comment: Here is my table structure http://imgur.com/oiliIQo

Comment: Why is it the email stored as  `ucs2_general_ci`?

Comment: I saw that as I posted and changed it. That was an error. After I altered in to utf8_general_ci it still doesn't like something.

Comment: Have you tried changing the whole path of your `header()` function? like: `header('location: http://localhost/admin/dashboard.php');`

Comment: Yea and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exit; or die();` after this line

```
if($count==1){
  $_SESSION['user']=$email;
  header('location: ../dashboard.php');    
  exit; or die();
}
```

if it not works tr this javascript code in place of header.

```
<?php 
$url = "http://localhost/admin/dashboard.php";
echo '<script> window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
?>
```

Hope It helps..

Answer (score 0):

After redirect use `die;` or `exit` . and before header location close session writing. and try to use complete path in `header(location:http://localhost/admin/dashboard.php')` like this. as suggest by some of my frirnds as well.

why use `exit` or `die`?

```
  header() won't automatically stop the script from excecuting.
```

Please try this:-

```
 session_write_close();
 header('Location: *where you want your form to go*');
 die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug this program like this :

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$qry="SELECT * FROM dontblame WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
var_dump($qry);
$result = mysql_query($qry);
var_dump($result);
```

make sure if the sql query is the same as you think .

or  "header('location: ../dashboard.php'); " has some problem!

Comment: FROM dontblame WHERE email='XXXXXXX@gmail.com' and password='e6a52beca192a3fd67c8a0ea52cdea29162dd265'" resource(3) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 0):

try using this ..

```
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password']));
```

next check `$count` value if it's till 0 then u have to use other method to convert password
or check for any spaces... Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you move to using mysqli instead because it is much more secure.
So here is a code snippet of your code implemented in mysqli.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "anon";
$password = "secret";
$schema = "your database name";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $schema);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT email FROM dontblame WHERE email=? and password=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
/* bind parameters */
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$pass);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

/* execute statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($result_email);

/* fetch values */
if($stmt->fetch()) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $resutl_email;
    $success = true;
} else {
    $success = false;
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

if($success){
    header('location: ../dashboard.php'); 
    exit();
} else {
    $login_err = "<p>Your email or password is incorrect.</p>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

I also closed the connection before redirecting for the sake of safe programming. mysqli has a lot more benefit than using the regular mysql methods, preparing parameters for queries is one of those benefits.

also, please hash and salt your passwords. thats the least you can do to protect your users' personal information in case you get hacked.